# c++ Exception thrown: read access violation as 0xDDDDDDDD on VS2015

Tags: c++11, sfml

im trying to build a snake game, and it works just fine, until i gameover, for some reason i get access violation right after the program ends, referring to this->actualState->

here is the code for the cpp file with working on actualState:

```
#include "Game.h"
using namespace sf;

Game::Game()
    :actualStateID(END)
{
    ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    window.create(VideoMode(SCRN_WIDTH, SCRN_HEIGHT), "Snake", Style::Close, settings);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    window.clear();
    window.display();

    if (!font.loadFromFile("data/font.ttf"))
    {
        //MessageBox(NULL, "Font not found! Chceck data folder!", "ERROR", NULL);
        return;
    }

    actualStateID = MENU;
}


Game::~Game()
{
}

void Game::runGame()
{
    actualState = new MenuState(MENU, window, font);
    actualState->init();

    while (actualStateID != END)
    {
        if (actualStateID != actualState->getSTATE_ID())
            changeState();

        handleState();
    }
    window.close();
}

void Game::changeState()
{
    delete actualState;

    switch (actualStateID)
    {
    case MENU:
        actualState = new MenuState(MENU, window, font);
        break;
    case PLAY_STATE:
        actualState = new PlayState(PLAY_STATE, window, font);
        break;
    case FAILURE:
        //Image screenShot = window.capture(); //DEPRECATEDDDDDD
        //Image screenShot = Texture.update(window);

        //actualState = new FailureState(FAILURE, window, font, screenShot);
        break;
    }

    actualState->init(); //error line!!
}

void Game::handleState()
{
    actualStateID = actualState->handleEvents(event);
    actualState->update();
    actualState->render();
}
```

i manage to track the exeption to line 63, but i dont seem to get it to work, srry im pretty new to c++ and sfml

here goes the state.cpp file as well as the detailed error(is there any more detail in VisualStudio?):
[error image with state.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ancF.png)
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

never mind, too many hours in front of the pc, uncomented actualstate = and change the failurestate code.